# Can't get OneSignal user id (cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, onesignal

Can't get OneSignal user id. I get error "Cannot read property OneSignal of undefined null"

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit(OneSingalID)
    .handleNotificationReceived(function (jsonData) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            removeNotications();
        }, 1000 * 60); // 1 min.
    })
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
    .endInit();

window.plugins.OneSignal.getUserId(function (id) { // <- error
    console.log(id)
});
```

This one didn't work too:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
    console.log(ids);
});
```

Comment: How are you loading the `OneSignalSDK`?

Comment: By adding plugin in config file. Forgot to mention it's phonegap project.

Comment: Is your `OneSignal` initialized after `deviceready` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a cordova expert, but searching on Google led me to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/347). This works when user has agreed to allow notifications if I'm not wrong.

Relevant code:

```
let me = this; window["plugins"].OneSignal .startInit("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXX") .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback).endInit();

window["plugins"].OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(function (state) { if (!state.from.subscribed && state.to.subscribed) { me.showAlertDialog('userId',state.to.userId); } me.showAlertDialog('state',JSON.stringify(state)); })
```

Link to documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--addsubscriptionobserver-